# MS Access: How do I have the database delete the LACCDB file on close?

Tags: database, windows, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a MS Access 2013 DB being shared by many users (Windows 7/8/10). For some reason, when they close the DB the LACCDB file remains. Opening this file up in a text editor, it tells me that User A has it open, yet she does not. Is there a way I can delete this file from inside the DB *on close*?

I can provide more info as needed.

Comment: The only reason it should not be deleted could be lack of Delete rights for this or all users.

Comment: The person listed in the LACCDB file has it locked, even though they may not have it open. You can look on that users machine for orphaned MSACCESS.exe processes or simply have them reboot. Then you will be able to delete that file.

Comment: This, or Access crashed on her. Note: you should split the database in frontend and backend and provide each user with their own local frontend.

Comment: @Andre we wanted to do that but we needed each user to write to **one** table. I was told that's not possible when you give each user a local copy.

Comment: @random_answer_guy might there be a way to write VBA code that will fully close the database and all parts of it? I read an article somewhere that `Application.Quit` only closes the major part of the DB but leaves a "shell" of the DB open. Do you know anything about that?

Comment: No sorry I don't. Usually its as Andre said the db crashes and is put in this state or the user closed a Form prematurely while code is running and the lock never clears. Also I don't think you can write code that will close it as all your users that are connected get listed in that file. Look at it while 3 people are actively using it and it should show all 3. If you force close after one user, it may kill their work too

Comment: The standard approach is to split the database, and give each user a copy of the software. This will thus allow each user to update the same table(s).

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I was told this isn't possible. Local copies can only write to their own tables.